# C++ - Read and compare user input?

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to programming.
I wanted to make an application that asks for your information and saves them into a text file (but that's coming up later).

I got stuck here, where I'm suppose to make the program read what the user input says:

```
char nimi[20];
int aika;
int ika;
char juoma[3];

cout << "Hello!\nWhat's your name?\n";
cin >> nimi;
cout << "\n\nHi ";
cout << nimi;
cout << "!\n";
cout << "\nES or MF?";
cin >> juoma;
```

The program should read if `juoma` is "ES" or "MF", and then execute some code depending on the answer.

If something like this would work, it'd solve it, but it won't:

```
if(juoma==ES){
cout << "Nice choice!"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(juoma=="ES")
{
   cout << "Nice choice!"
}
```

You were missing the double quotes. You need to have your variable juoma declared as `std::string` to work. Working with char arrays in C++ is plain torture, don't do that.

Comment: `cin >> juoma;

if(juoma=="ES") {
                cout << "Hyva valinta!\n";
                }
                
else if(juoma=="MF") {
                     cout << "Hyi! Juo ES!";
                     }`

Answer (score 0):

As nvoigt suggested: you have to add double quotes, with that the compiler will be able to create a temporary std::string object and use it to compare it with juoma:

A possible solution that uses const std::string objects would be:

```
const std::string esCompareHelper("ES");    
const std::string mfCompareHelper("MF");

if( (esCompareHelper == juoma) || (mfCompareHelper == juoma) )
{
   // your specialized code
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a bit complicated compared to nvoigt's answer?

Comment: The intension was to point out the operator overloading  functionality of C++ and the created temporarary objects, because the author wrote: "I'm pretty new to programming"